# ObjectStateManager state not changed after updating

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I want to get all properties which has been changed after updating, actually I change some of the properties not all of them and I want to know which one has been updated!! I used ObjectStateManager to get the ***state*** of the entry but it always shows ***UNCHANGED*** !! can any one help me please

```
var db = new DataAccess.ApplicationDbContext();
var employee_db = db.Employees.Find(employee.Id);
employee_db.Tell = employee.Tell;
employee_db.EmailAddress = employee.EmailAddress
db.SaveChanges();

ObjectStateEntry entry = 
 ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(employee_db);


        foreach (string property in entry.GetModifiedProperties())
                {
    ...// just jump out of the loop, means nothing changed
    }
```

actually my changes are saved correctly but the state shows unchanged

I also used refresh method for employee_db but it does not solve the problem

***EDITED***

I want to get all changed properties by this code

```
       foreach (string property in entry.GetModifiedProperties())
            {

                object oldValue = entry.OriginalValues[property];
                object newValue = entry.CurrentValues[property];
}
```

Comment: Looks like the properties didn't actually change. You assigned the same values. BTW I don't understand the comment *just jump out of the loop, means nothing changed*. If you're in the loop it would mean something *was* changed.

Comment: sorry, I explained a little confusing, it does not go into the loop, the property change and I see changed value after savechange on the database. but after savechanges the state shows unchanged!!

Comment: Well of course they are unchanged *after* `SaveChanges`. The state tell EF what needs to be updated in the database.

Comment: I just searched for "How to get changed properties" and I found above solution, so whats wrong and how can I reach that? thanks

Comment: You almost answered this question yourself. You don't see the changed properties *after* `SaveChanges`. What about *before*?

Comment: I SEE changes , the property IS changed correctly, even on db and on debug mode , I can see all changes!! but what about the code on EDITED section, what is it for so?